# wxWidgets OnInit

Tags: wxwidgets

This code works fine:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, -1, _("Hello World"), wxPoint(50, 50),
                                  wxSize(450, 350));       
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame frame(NULL, -1, _("Hello World"), wxPoint(50, 50),
                                  wxSize(450, 350));       
    frame.Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

It doesn't give any compilation/link/execution error, just don't show up the window. Why this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Show` function returns immediately so the `wxFrame` object is destroyed right away (as it is created on stack) -> so there is nothing to display.

If you create the frame using `new` the object is not destroyed after exiting the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to create wxWindow classes (wxFrame, panel etc.) on stack, you should only create it on heap. It is explained in detail in the[wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Avoiding_Memory_Leaks#Child_windows) and in the [docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_multiplatform.html#page_multiplatform_allocatingobjects).

[INS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269379/3458969) is also correct, but the only way to create a wx application is NOT through a memory leak. wxWidgets deletes it's wxWindow classes automatically after the program has finished executing. So that's why we're not deleting the class (nor the wxApp you're using). For the rest of the objects you can use the wxApp::OnExit() function for manually deletion of any other data on heap.

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
    virtual int OnExit();

private:
    wxFrame *m_frame;
    int *m_foo;
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    m_frame = new wxFrame(nullptr, -1, wxT("No leaks"), wxPoint(-1, -1),
                          wxSize(300, 200));
    m_frame->Show(true);
    m_foo = new int(2);

    return true;
}

int MyApp::OnExit(){
    // Any custom deletion here
    // DON'T call delete m_frame or m_frame->Destroy() m_frame here
    // As it is null at this point.
    delete m_foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, thx for links +1, i was trying to use static wxFrame instance which is not destroyed in OnInit scope (like in question) and i still got runtime error (this is nullptr) now i know why :)